# Error term in Taylor approximations of $\sin$ and other series with zero derivatives of higher order

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

The taylor polynomial of many functions has a skip term due to the fact that some derivative of the function is 0, $f^{(i)}(a) = 0$. For example, the sine function can be written as follows:

$$\text{T}_{2n + 2}(\sin(x; 0)) = \sum_\limits{k = 0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k + 1)!}x^{2k + 1} + E_{2n + 2}(x)$$ where $$E_{2n + 2}(x) = \frac{1}{(2n + 2)!}\int_{0}^x(x - t)^{2n + 2}\sin^{(2n+3)}(t)dt$$

However, we know that the term $2n + 2$ is actually missing in the sum, because it is zero. However, even though the term is missing, we can try to construct a polynomial of 1 degree lower: $2n + 1$ and write the error term differently even though the Taylor polynomial does not change at all:

$$\text{T}_{2n + 1}(\sin(x; 0)) = \sum_\limits{k = 0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k + 1)!}x^{2k + 1} + E_{2n + 1}(x)$$ where $$E_{2n + 1}(x) = \frac{1}{(2n + 1)!}\int_{0}^x(x - t)^{2n + 1}\sin^{(2n+2)}(t)dt$$

Due to uniqueness of Taylor polynomials, $E_{2n + 1} = E_{2n + 2}$ then (Taylor polynomial is the same, and error is equal for 2 different degrees of the polynomial). Is it the correct conclusion? If it is, why in my textbook and everywhere on the internet people use the term $E_{2n + 2}$ instead of $E_{2n + 1}$, and for other series with skip-terms, like $\arctan$ and $\cos$?

Comment: Because when you estimate the error terms (and, typically, most people use the Lagrange form, which is far easier to estimate) you will get a *smaller* error bound using $E_{2n+2}$ than using $E_{2n+1}$. Almost never do (or, indeed, can) you actually easily compute these error integrals exactly.

Comment: @TedShifrin, but how is it possible that there is a smaller bound with $E_{2n + 2}$ if I concluded above^ that they are equal with $E_{2n + 1}$? Is my "proof" incorrect then? I am working through Apostol book, so he never really discussed this issue, so I was wondering if maybe i'm missing some detail here.

Comment: Yes, the remainder in the same in both cases.  What you are overlooking is that you won't be able to compute the remainder exactly.  You'll just compute a bound on the absolute value.  Therefore, you'll want to use the expression that makes it possible to compute a smaller bound.

Comment: Ah, ok, I got it. Didn't understand the comment about the bound first. Now clear. Thx TedShifrin, saulspatz